# Is there something in XQuery similar to LIMIT x, y in SQL?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I need to paginate the results of queries in XQuery. Is there something similar to LIMIT X,y in SQL?

Comment: Indeed what I'm looking for is a way to paginate the result of a query in XQuery. Not so obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the size of a result sequence with the [fn:subsequence](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_subsequence.html) function.

Comment: I think that fn:subsequence returns the subsequence of an sequence  of an XML document. You have first to get the whole sequence and then use that sequence to get the subsequence. Each time you have to get first the whole sequence. This is not the way that LIMIT works in SQL, in SQL there is not previous retrieve of the whole query and then ask for a subset of the result.

Comment: It will be up to the implementation to decide if the full sequence will be processed. BaseX will stop the evaluation once the requested number of results is returned.

Comment: Thank you so much!!